# can I save a window object inside a localStorage

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to open a page with a button, and kill the page with another button.

I think that it saves the page object as text, any way arround that?

```
<button onClick="initiate()">open page</button>
<button onClick="kill()">kill page</button>


<script>
function initiate()
{
var w=window.open("https://www.google.com/");
localStorage.setItem('urlmem', w);
}

function kill()
{
a = localStorage.getItem('urlmem')
prompt(a)
a.window.close()
}
</script>
```

Comment: You could just save the w somewhere and call .close() on that.

Answer (score 6):

> can I save a window object inside a localStorage

**No.**

`localStorage` can only store strings and `window` objects are not serializable to strings. And even if they were, there is no API to recreate a `window` object from a string.

> any way arround that?

It looks like you don't need persistent storage at all. Just save the the reference in a variable that is visible to both functions.

```
var w;

function initiate() {
    w = window.open(...);
}

function kill() {
    w.close();
}
```

There are better ways to organize your code, but that should give you the idea.