# Storing the Window Object in local storage

Tags: javascript, json, popup, local-storage

I need the ability to persist the window object. I tried to stringify the window object but I received and error when trying to convert the window object to JSON.  "Converting circular structure to JSON" error. Is there anyway I can store the window object from a window.open in local store?

```
var myWindow = window.open("file:///D:/Temp/teststorage.html", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
localStorage.setItem('Window', JSON.stringify(myWindow));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can I save a window object inside a localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515056/can-i-save-a-window-object-inside-a-localstorage)

Answer (score 4):

You can't persist a `window` object in local storage.

You can only store data in the form of strings in local storage, and there is no way to turn the `window` object into a string so that you can recreate the same `window` object.

Comment: The window object contains the JSON object. That's why you cant stringify it. What you should do is to store **some** elements of the window  into an object, and then store it in the local storage.

Comment: I need the ability of checking if the window object is open on every page of the application. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: @Victor: Not exactly. You can use `var myWindow = window.open('', 'MsgWindow');` to get the `window` object for a window if it exists, but if it didn't exist it will open a new blank window. You can however check if the window has a document loaded to see if it existed or if you just created it.